# CSS hover to expand inputbox and pause to allow input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to learn how I can hover over a search icon which then expands the inputbox which will allow a user to enter some details in. So far I have found a css solution for the hover but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to do this? Please help.

This is the jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/amosangyongjian/xzo0kaj5/

This is the html/css that doesn't seem to work

```
<input type="text" class="search"/>
<span class="searchicon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>

.search{
  display:none;
  width:0;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.searchicon:hover~.search{
  display:block;
  width:197px;
}
```

Comment: You want to display a textbox on the hover of search icon?

Comment: Yes and then not close if when I input text into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ~ selector matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first. To make this work you could put input after the span in the html. I think you may find that only using css to achieve this has its limitations, a better option may be to apply the class using js to show the input so you have more control. I added some additional css selectors (.search:hover, .search:focus) to overcome some of the problems I saw.

```css
.search{
  width:0;
  visibility: hidden; /* display property wasn't working with transition */
  transition: width 2s;
  float: left;
}

.searchicon:hover~.search, .search:hover, .search:focus{
  visibility: visible;
  width:197px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="searchicon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="search"/>
```

Basic example for handling with jquery:

```js
$('.searchicon').hover(function() {
  $('.search').addClass('show');  
});
```

```css
.search{
  width:0;
  visibility: hidden; /* display property wasn't working with transition */
  transition: width 2s;
  float: left;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  width:197px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="searchicon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="search"/>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. What would the jquery option look like? I'm open to it but i'm not too familiar with jquery

Comment: I added a very basic example to the answer. Really, it all depends on how exactly you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.searchicon:hover~.search` query is not working because it selects every `.search` element that are preceded by a `.searchicon:hover` element. In your case, the `.searchicon:hover` precedes the `.search`, so its not going to work.

The effect will be triggered if you move the input text after the span tag,  like this:

```
<span class="searchicon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="search"/>
```

[There is no a previuous sibling selector in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), so if you want to keep that html structure you should use javascript to achieve this.